# intercept javascript call

Tags: javascript, android, webkit

I've run into an interesting problem with an android development project. I was charged to interface the company's online database to an android app. The database has a call to a javascript that looks like this.

```
<a href="javascript:foo(9.7);">9.7</a>
```

The request of the app was to have the javascript be able to run locally on the app. I've been able to intercept the script call by overriding the onJsPrompt method but cannot retrieve the value that is sent to the java script in-order to process the user input.

I can parse the data once it is retreived, but I'm lost on how to get the actual call from the website to the script.

Tried getUrl function, but that returns the page that I'm on not the script call.

Any help/input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my error was annoyingly simple. I created an override for onJsPrompt. It was partly a concession among my colleagues and the higher-ups that we were not ready for a release that had the amount of caching that we wanted and at the end of the override I did not send back the value needed that the user enters which looks something like this

```
final EditText input = new EditText(myApp);
                prompt.setView(input);

                prompt.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                    {
                        Editable value = input.getText();
                        result.confirm(value.toString());*
                    }
                });
```

I simply forgot to put the value that the user entered back to the confirm. Annoying but it is now fixed and has the amount of functionality we need so far.